# AngularJS Wiris integration

Tags: angularjs, integration, mathml

I'm a beginner at AngularJS. As a first project, I'm trying to set up a simple Angular project which integrates [Wiris](http://www.wiris.com/plugins/docs/full-mathml-mode).

[image]

Actually seeing and interacting with the plugin is the extent of my progress. My problems begin when I try to get the data in the textarea.

I try using the following approach:

```
<div ng-model="questionData" id="editorContainer"
     style='width:100%; height:500px;'>
  Responsible!
</div>
<input type="button" value="Submit" ng-click="postQuestion()" />
```

```js
headlessQS.controller('wirisController', ['$scope', '$route', '$routeParams', function($scope, $route, $routeParams){

    $scope.postQuestion = function(){
//        console.log($scope.questionData.wrs_previewImage);
//        console.log( angular.element('#editorContainer').val() );
//        console.log( $('#editorContainer').val() );
//        console.log(angular.element('[id="username"]').val());
//        console.log(angular.element('#editorContainer').html);

        console.log( angular.element('#editorContainer').val() );
        console.log( angular.element('#editorContainer')[0].value );
    }
}]);
```

I tried each one of those `console.log` statements unsuccessfully but something tells me my general approach is wrong.

I am looking to integrate Wiris with AngularJS2 so that I can retrieve the formula created. How can I do that?

Comment: `angular.element()` does not provide selectors like jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to access the MathML markup is via the `getMathML()` Wiris api function call as shown below:

```
$scope.postQuestion = function(){
    console.log( editor.getMathML() );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ng-model` directive does not work with `<div>` elements.

> ERRONEOUS
>
> ```
> <div ng-model="questionData" id="editorContainer"
>      style='width:100%; height:500px;'>
>   Responsible!
> </div>
> ```

BETTER

```
<textarea ng-model="questionData" id="editorContainer"
     style='width:100%; height:500px;'>
  Responsible!
</textarea>
```

---

## Integrating `ng-model` with `<div>` elements

To integrate `ng-model` with a `<div>` element, define a custom directive that works with the ng-model controller:

```
<div ng-model="questionData" my-editor>
    Responsible!
</div>

app.directive("myEditor", function() {
    return {
        require: "ngModel",
        link: postLink
    };
    function postLink(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
        elem.on("keyup", function(ev) {
            var keycode = ev.keyCode;
            //...
            ctrl.$setViewValue(data);
        });
        ctrl.$render = function() {
            var something = $ctrl.$viewValue;
            //...
            elem.html(something);
        };
        ctrl.$parsers.push(function(data) {
            //...
            return data;
        });
        ctrl.$formatters.push(function(data) {
            //...
            return data;
        });            
    }
})
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Implementing custom form controls (using `ngModel`)](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#implementing-custom-form-controls-using-ngmodel-)
- [AngularJS ngModelController API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#ngModel.NgModelController-methods)
- [AngularJS ngModelController API Reference - Custom Control Example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#custom-control-example)